# Universally required fields

Tags: required-field

Which field cannot be universally required in salesforce?
a)Look Up
b)Text
c)Email
4)Number
I refer some guide it is given Answer a)Lookup
but when i tried to make lookup field required ,its working.
Please Help me out in this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: When posting questions such as this, which obviously come from a test or exam, can you provide details of where it came from?  That way we can be sure you aren't sharing questions from real Salesforce certification exams and breaching the test taker agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make lookup fields universally required in the initial field setup.  the documentation is generally very good but sometimes it's not perfect.  usually the reason it is not perfect is that sales force makes something possible but doesn't update every single existing piece of documentation with the latest update or upgrade.

I think at the time of its writing you could not do this, but now you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup can be made mandatory now .This was recently launched in API 25.0 version so none of the answers are correct.

In API version 25.0 salesforce made lot of changes to Master Detail and also for lookup relationship.

http://na3.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_spring12_release_notes.pdf

Above is summer 12 release notes .Please go through the same .

Thanks